# Is there any way to get executable file for Dart console project?

Tags: dart, console-application, executable

Is there any way to compile my dart console project to executable file?
Or maybe there are some utilities like `launch4j` for `Java`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't really have all of the pieces together for that – yet.

I'd take a look through this issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34343

I'll find the right person on the team to reply here with more details.

Answer (score 1):

We can build Dart project to a native app via `dart2native`.

For example we have `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:ansicolor/ansicolor.dart';

main(List<String> arguments) {
  AnsiPen greenPen = AnsiPen()..green();
  AnsiPen greenBackGroundPen = AnsiPen()..green(bg: true);

  AnsiPen redTextBlueBackgroundPen = AnsiPen()..blue(bg: true)..red();

  AnsiPen boldPen = AnsiPen()..white(bold: true);

  AnsiPen someColorPen = AnsiPen()..rgb(r: .5, g: .2, b: .4);

  print(greenPen("Hulk") + " " + greenBackGroundPen("SMASH!!!"));
  print(redTextBlueBackgroundPen("Spider-Man!!!") + " " + boldPen("Far From Home!!!"));

  print(someColorPen("Chameleon"));

  print('\x1B[94m' + "hahAHaHA!!!" + '\x1B[0m');
}
```

And `pubspec.yaml` as

```
name: colored_text_test
description: A sample command-line application.

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  ansicolor: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.0.0
```

We can use command `dart2native.bat bin\main.dart` and get `main.exe` as executable output.

Also we can specify name by using `-o` option: `dart2native main.dart -o my_app`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this capability [was added in Dart 2.6](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart2native-a76c815e6baf).

In newer Dart versions, the `dart2native` tool was integrated into the `dart` binary. See the tutorial [Write command-line apps](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/cmdline%5D) on [dart.dev](https://dart.dev) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dart compile](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile) for this.

```
dart compile exe path/to/main/script.dart
```